# CartoDB.js/Leaflet map - how can I click between multipolygons cleanly?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, carto, geojson, carto-js

Here's my map:
https://jsfiddle.net/Sidders/4exf969e/3/

I want to apply a click and hover effect to the polygons. So a polygon/multipolygon highlights on hover, and is selected with one click. The hover effect resets on 'mouseOut', and the select effect resets when another polygon/multipolygon is selected.

However, when I click between multipolygons (e.g. see the islands around Scotland) they don't fully 'reset' and some polygons stay highlighted. It becomes a mess, and I think it's because `e.layer` does not work with multipolygons.

How do I amend my code so I can cleanly select and click between multipolygons on my map?

Comment: The link is not working